# Exe from cx_Freeze Program is Missing Module

Tags: python, python-3.5

I built a program with cx_Freeze (3.5.0 64 bit) where my setup looked like

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    setup(name='TOOL11',
          version ='0.1',
          description='Easily find best float combination',
          executables = [Executable("TOOL11.py")])
```

But when I run the tool11.exe that's in the build folder, the cmd opens and closes super quickly. I recorded this happening and played it back frame by frame to see the error: https://i.gyazo.com/fe6ec4b8743e2348c48ee927ac8c1284.png
It seems that the error was that the google module wasn't installed in the build folder. Seeing this I added import google to my TOOL11.py and tried to build again. I tried running the exe again but I get the same error.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you tried to add import google.
Have you tried this ?

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(name='TOOL11',
      version ='0.1',
      description='Easily find best float combination',
      options={"build_exe": {"includes":["google"]}},
      executables = [Executable("TOOL11.py")])
```

Comment: I tried to add google by putting `import google` in the TOOL11.py file. I just ran the setup.py where it looked like this: `from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(name='TOOL11',
      version ='0.1',
      description='Easily find best float combination',
      options={"build_exe": {"includes":["google"]}},
      executables = [Executable("TOOL11.py")])`

but got this error: http://pastebin.com/LTXCvi86

Comment: Other solution : you can dowload this file : (https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py), put it into your steam folder and modify the line `from google.protobuf.internal.python_message import GeneratedProtocolMessageType as _ProtoMessageType` to `from python_message import GeneratedProtocolMessageType as _ProtoMessageType`

Comment: I see in the build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\steam\util  there is a _init_ file but it is already compiled and looks like this: https://i.gyazo.com/ec19235655fcd0236af3a62d42d2b11f.png Line 10 is also blank. Is this the file/folder you meant?

Comment: No, it's ``c:\Python35\lib\site-packages\steam\util\__init__.py``

Comment: I tried commenting out line 10 but that didn't work. Downloaded python_message.py and put it in C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\steam\util. Tried building again with my previous setup.py (not including the include google line) but still just opened and closed the cmd super quickly. Am I still supposed to build with the description line in the setup.py? is python_message.py supposed to be in steam folder or in util folder? Thanks Edit: tried with python_messages in the just Steam folder not unnder util, but it still just opens and closes super quick

Comment: No, the option line in the setup is no more useful. Yes, python_message.py  has to be in util folder. Perhaps an other error occured ? Does your script run before freezing ?

Comment: Changed setup.py to your code. Put python_messages.py into util folder and changed the line you said to. tried running the build but got this again: http://pastebin.com/TkXm2BdF Edit: when running the exe it opens and closes super quick and I don't have time to see what it says.

Comment: OK, try to delete the ``c:\python\...\steam\__pycache__`` folder

Comment: Sorry, had to leave unexpectedly. I removed to pycache but still get `ImportError: No module named 'google'` when running `Python35\Python setup.py build`. Also, my program doesn't work with the python_message. http://pastebin.com/Qy6j4QmB . Thanks again for trying to help me

Comment: I read on Steam doc : "By default the steam package doesn’t install all dependecies. Add [client] extra if you are going to use SteamClient :
pip install -U steam[client]". Have you made this ?

Comment: Before I only did `pip install -U steam`. Still gives the `ImportError: no module named google` when building though

Comment: Not necessary. So you typed `pip install -U steam[client]` and still error? Have a folder google in`c:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ ?

Comment: Yes, I do have a google folder there. Inside is "protobuf"

Comment: So I assume your program is running normally, only freezing throw a bug. We have to make it work with Cx-Freeze : you can reverse the modifications and try `from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable setup(name='TOOL11', version ='0.1', description='Easily find best float combination', options={"build_exe": {"includes":["goggle","google.protobuf"],"path": sys.path}}, executables = [Executable("TOOL11.py")])`

Comment: `C:\Users\.Anderson\Documents\Python\Floats1\NEWEST\EXE>c:\python35\python setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    options={"build_exe": {"includes":["goggle","google.protobuf"],"path": sys.path}},
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`

also, in options should it be goggle or google?

Comment: excuse me : `import sys` before `from cx_Freeze...`

Comment: Ran it but still get `ImportError: No module names 'google'` Is cxfreeze really the best way to go? Or is there another way that might work better?

Comment: To distribute your app you can try PyInstaller or Py2exe. But both have problems with python 3.5. Since I had a lot of problem making Cx-Freeze 5.0 run on Python 3.5, I went back to python 3.4 and cx-freeze 4.3.4 who actually works. Good luck !

Comment: You think going back to python 3.4 and cx-freeze 4.3.4 will solve the google module issue?

Comment: I just remembered, the only reason I'm using python 3.5 is because some of my modules only worked on 3.5. I don't know what to do

Comment: Alright, I figured out how to install the modules I needed on python 3.4.0. I then installed cx_freeze 4.3.4. With `from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name='FloatTool14',
      version='0.1',
      description='Find best float',
      executables = [Executable("FloatTool14.py")])
` as my setup it let me bulid the exe, but when opeining the exe still gave `Importerror: no module named 'google'` and when using the setup.py method you suggested, it gives me the error of no module named google in the console. I can try going back through the other steps in a bit.